# Faraday's Law applied to an airplane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

Consider an airplane flying from west to east. A question I'm working on says that the top of the right wing is most likely to develop a positive electrical charge. I get why it would be the top of the wing, not bottom, but I do not understand why it is the right wing that is most likely to develop a positive electrical charge.

Here is my logic for why it would be the top of the wing: Earth's magnetic field lines go from the geographical south pole to the north pole, and viewing the airplane from the south pole, the field lines go into the page. The airplane is moving from left to right. Using the right hand rule for $q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}$, the force on a free electron is down the page, leaving a relatively positive top end of the wing.

I just do not see the logic behind why the right wing will develop a positive electrical charge. I am a high school student and this question is aimed at high school students, so I do not think I am missing any fundamental concepts, but I just can't work this out.

Comment: Do you know which hemisphere the plane is on? Might have an effect on the angle of the B-field.

Comment: @Codename47 Yes, it's in the southern hemisphere (Australia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that the plane wings are parallel with the ground. Since the plane is in the southern hemisphere, the Earth's magnetic field lines are not parallel with the ground (this is only a good approximation at the equator).

Your answer implicitly assumes that the B-field is parallel with the wings. If you drop that assumption, you should be able to work it out.